# Libc6 is broken

Tags: package-management, libc6, synaptic

After updating python version libc6 was broken on my Ubuntu 12.04

I have libc6 2.18-4 and it broken.

It was installed from unstable repo. From precise repo I see 2.15.0 version of libc6. But if I try to force it, I see long list of "To be removed" packages. How can I prevent this deletion and fix my libc6?

Error message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
 libc6:i386 (2.18-4) breaks locales (<< 2.18) and is installed.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
 libc6 (2.18-4) breaks locales (<< 2.18) and is installed.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
dpkg: error processing locales (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: What command did you run to update Python? What error message is telling you that libc6 is broken? What was installed from the unstable repo and which repo was it? It's probably not worth the time to figure all that out. Just re-image the machine and restore the data from backup.

Comment: I just opened synaptic and updated python version. How I can get the error message? I haven't a backup...

Comment: Synaptic? You have a windowing system on this server? And no backups? Is your system still usable enough to make a backup?  If so, do that first.

Comment: Added an edit, waiting for response

Comment: @Ladadadada, I'm waiting

Comment: Is that working for you?  It never has for me.  If I had a login to your server there's a chance I could fix it but much of it would be a learning process, not something I have done before.  Solving it by going back and forth in the comments is not going to work.  Not even if I was being paid to do it.  With your level of experience (which I'm guessing is low) fixing the system is unlikely to ever happen and my original advice still stands which is to backup the data and re-install from scratch.

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry you can't do it.

I haven't backup and it's my very long living computer. I have this computer working since 2011.

Comment: I'm just a ruby coder. And it seems I solved the issue. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `libc6` library depends on `2.13+git20120306-3`. But I can't repair `libc6` without installing a `locales 2.18-4`. So, I just replaced `locales` with the `locales-all 2.18-4` and removed the annoting `locales` library.

Problem solved! There isn't a conflict now!